# Clean up process throws an exception (itextsharp)

Tags: itext

I get an exception when trying to cleanup a section of a PDF (text searchable). It only happens on some PDFs. I noticed the difference is the text might be a little bit skewed.

I create some annotations of the PDF. Save it to file, then use the cleanup procedure. It works like a charm on most of the PDFs.

(itextsharp: 5.5.13.0)

Thanks in advance.

```
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
   at iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpRenderListener.ProcessImage(Byte[] imageBytes, IList`1 areasToBeCleaned)
   at iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpRenderListener.RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.ImageXObjectDoHandler.HandleXObject(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfStream xobjectStream, PdfIndirectReference refi, ICollection markedContentInfoStack)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.DisplayXObject(PdfName xobjectName)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.Do.Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
   at iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpContentOperator.Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor pdfContentStreamProcessor, PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.InvokeOperator(PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfDictionary resources)
   at iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.CleanUpPage(Int32 pageNum, IList`1 cleanUpLocations)
   at iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.CleanUp()
   at AU.PDF.Redaction.PdfProcessor.Redact(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath, IEnumerable`1 options) in C:\Users\Depen585\Documents\POC\Redaction\AU.PDF.Redaction\PdfProcessor.cs:line 123
   at Poc.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Depen585\Documents\POC\Redaction\Poc\Program.cs:line 91
```

**UPDATE**

Bruno, using your method I get this error now (works with some, fails with others):

```
   at iText.PdfCleanup.PdfCleanUpFilter.FilterImage(ImageRenderInfo image, IList`1 imageAreasToBeCleaned)
   at iText.PdfCleanup.PdfCleanUpFilter.FilterImage(FilteredImageKey imageKey)
   at iText.PdfCleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.CheckIfImageAndClean(IList`1 operands)
   at iText.PdfCleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.FilterContent(String operator, IList`1 operands)
   at iText.PdfCleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.InvokeOperator(PdfLiteral operator, IList`1 operands)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfResources resources)
   at iText.PdfCleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfResources resources)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.ProcessPageContent(PdfPage page)
   at iText.PdfCleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.ProcessPageContent(PdfPage page)
   at iText.PdfCleanup.PdfCleanUpTool.CleanUpPage(Int32 pageNumber, IList`1 cleanUpLocations)
   at iText.PdfCleanup.PdfCleanUpTool.CleanUp()
   at AU.PDF.PdfProcessor.Redact(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath, String textToRedact) in C:\Users\Depen585\Documents\POC\Redaction\AU.PDF\PdfProcessor.cs:line 38
   at Poc.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Depen585\Documents\POC\Redaction\Poc\Program.cs:line 91
```

Here is the code:

```
public class PdfProcessor
{
    public void Initialize(string licenseKeyFilePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(licenseKeyFilePath)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(licenseKeyFilePath));

        LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile(licenseKeyFilePath);
    }

    public void Redact(string inputFilePath, string outputFilePath, string textToRedact)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputFilePath)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputFilePath));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(outputFilePath)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outputFilePath));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textToRedact)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(textToRedact));

        //CompositeLocationExtractionStrategy strategy = new CompositeLocationExtractionStrategy();

        //strategy.add(new PatternLocationExtractionStrategy(textToRedact).setRedactionColor(Color.PINK));

        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFilePath))
        using (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputFilePath))
        using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, writer))
        {
            List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new List<PdfCleanUpLocation>
            {
                new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new Rectangle(97, 405, 383, 40), iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.BLACK)
            };

            new PdfCleanUpTool(pdf, cleanUpLocations).CleanUp();

            //PdfAutoSweep autoSweep = new PdfAutoSweep(composite);

            //autoSweep.CleanUp(pdf);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Even with custom strategy (RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy) it fails on the same PDFS. See below...

```
public class RegexLocationExtractionStrategy : RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy, ICleanupStrategy
{
    private readonly string Regex;

    public RegexLocationExtractionStrategy(string regex) : base(regex)
    {
        Regex = regex ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(regex));
    }

    public Color GetRedactionColor(IPdfTextLocation location)
    {
        return ColorConstants.BLACK;
    }

    public ICleanupStrategy Reset()
    {
        return new RegexLocationExtractionStrategy(Regex);
    }
}

public class PdfProcessor
{
    public void Initialize(string licenseKeyFilePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(licenseKeyFilePath)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(licenseKeyFilePath));

        LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile(licenseKeyFilePath);
    }

    public void Redact(string inputFilePath, string outputFilePath, string regex)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputFilePath)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputFilePath));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(outputFilePath)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outputFilePath));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(regex)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(regex));

        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFilePath))
        using (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputFilePath))
        using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, writer))
        {
            var strategy = new RegexLocationExtractionStrategy(regex);

            PdfAutoSweep autoSweep = new PdfAutoSweep(strategy);

            autoSweep.CleanUp(pdf);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 3:**

I can see the redaction annotations when I use the tentative cleanup. Then I pass the clean up locations to the redaction routine and it fails all the same. See below.

```
public IEnumerable<PdfCleanUpLocation> Annotate(string inputFilePath, string outputFilePath, string regex)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputFilePath)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputFilePath));
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(outputFilePath)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outputFilePath));
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(regex)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(regex));

    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFilePath))
    using (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputFilePath))
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, writer))
    {
        var strategy = new RegexLocationExtractionStrategy(regex);
        var autoSweep = new PdfAutoSweep(strategy);

        autoSweep.TentativeCleanUp(pdf);

        return autoSweep.GetPdfCleanUpLocations(pdf);
    }
}


public void Redact(string inputFilePath, string outputFilePath, IEnumerable<PdfCleanUpLocation> locations)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputFilePath)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputFilePath));
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(outputFilePath)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outputFilePath));
    if (locations == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(locations));

    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFilePath))
    using (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputFilePath))
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, writer))
    {
        var cleanUpTool = new PdfCleanUpTool(pdf);

        locations
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(location => cleanUpTool.AddCleanupLocation(location));

        cleanUpTool.CleanUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: please share your code block with hints for better answer.

Comment: 5.5.13 is a *maintenance* release of the old iText 5 (we don't call it iTextSharp anymore). The cleanup functionality in iText 5 was experimental and prepared for a separate add-on called [pdfSweep](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfsweep). That add-on was created on top of iText 7. Have you tried iText 7 with pdfSweep? Does the error also exist in that version? Note that you might not get an iText 5 answer because iText 5 is being phased out. We only look at iText 5 if a customer with a paid support contract encounters a problem.

Comment: Thank you both for responding. Bruno, I was just working on a POC using the version provided by nuget. I ll give iText 7 a try. Again thank you both.

Comment: Bruno, using your method I get this error now:

Comment: Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated =)

Comment: As you say that issue only occurs for some pdfs and not for others, it very likely depends on the specific pdf and/or your redaction coordinates in it. Thus, please share a sample pdf and redaction parameters.

Comment: mkl, I sent the PDFs to Lebo Morodi <lebo.morodi@itextpdf.com>, not sure how to do the same in this thread =(

Comment: @AlbertoDePena To get help on stackoverflow, you should not send the sample data to individuals but create a public share (google drive, dropbox, ...) and post the URL for it here in your question.

Comment: Thus, please share a sample pdf and redaction parameters.